# Does dividing both sides of a differential equation by a function make it a different differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My confusion started when I encountered the following problem in a problem set. The problem asked to classify the following ordinary differential equation.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 5y + y^2$

For some reason, my first thought was to rearrange the equation like so

$\frac{dy}{5y + y^2} = dx$

$\frac{dy}{5y + y^2} - dx = 0$

$(\frac{1}{5y + y^2})dy + (-1)dx = 0$

This seems to be exact because $\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} = 0 = \frac{\partial N}{\partial y}$

The answer key however said that this equation was not exact, only seperable. This is already strange to me because I'm pretty sure every seperable equation is also exact.

I'm wondering if the answer key is simply wrong, or if I made a mistake by dividing both sides by $5y + y^2$. Can it really be considered the "same" differential equation if I divide both sides by a function? Or does it become a new equation that is exact although the original equation wasn't?

Answer (score 1):

There are slight differences. The solution of an exact DE is a curve in the $(x,y)$ plane that is tangent in each point to the kernel of the differential form.

The solution of a differential equation is a function $y(x)$, that is, one concrete parametrization of the above curves, using $x$ as independent variable and thus restricting the curve to segments that are monotonous in $x$.

One could say that the implicit solution of the separation method is more a curve equation than a function, so it is not completely wrong to see the incomplete integral symbolic as exact DE. But usually this is not the level of an intro course, where $\frac{dy}{g(y)}=f(x)dx$ is an informal way of writing $\int \frac{dy}{g(y)}=\int f(x) dx$.

---

You can here avoid the partial fraction decomposition by dividing just by $y^2$, that is, treating the equation as Bernoulli DE.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is my first differential equations course so a lot of these concepts are new to me. I'm confused how you're asserting a difference between the solution to an exact DE and a differential equation when an exact DE is a differential equation.

Comment: Another thing is that you said that it's not wrong to see the incomplete integral symbolic as an exact DE, but does that imply that the differential equation I started with is exact is my question.

Comment: No, they are not the same. Exact DE define a direction field (outside of singular points) while ODE define a vector field. These concepts are similar, they can be, in general, partially transformed into each other, but not the same. // No, you start with a separable ODE. As such it is expected to find a function as ODE solution. In this special case that is possible, in general you only get an implicit solution form from a separable ODE. Using the incomplete integral symbolic as intermediate step is ok, but stating that this is an exact DE requires safeguards to be equivalent.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. So when I divided both sides of the equation by 5y + y^2 I made the equation go from a DE to an exact DE, when it was only separable before. So if I avoid dividing by a function and rearrange it into dy - (5y + y^2)dx = 0, would that allow it to remain the same separable ode?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is, as an indivisible symbol, the same as $y'(x)$. $M\,dx+N\,dy=0$ is a symbolic expression for the tuple $(M,N)$. You can connect them via the chain rule, as long as it is applicable. Modern mathematics only knows $dx$, $dy$ on their own as static symbols, as linear functionals. The dynamical version as vanishing quantities or infinitesimals is better left in history. Modern reconstructions of infinitesimals have them also as static (but not constructible) quantities.